# Are there any caveats in using Objectify with Google Cloud Endpoints on App Engine Java?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm developing an app on Appengine & Android, and am planning to use Google Cloud Endpoints for the API and GCM for the communications between the cloud and mobile. I had intended to use Objectify for the data persistence, but am wondering if I will run into unexpected trouble with it - particularly with different annotations, or other requirements. Does anyone have any experience they can warn me about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objectify is considered a supported framework for use with Endpoints, so if you encounter issues, they'd be viewed as bugs. A number of trusted testers have been using it with success.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Would getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.objectify.Work" when generating Endpoint library from a class which includes an Objectify Transaction be considered a bug in my code, my design, my Eclipse setup, or either Objectify (4.0b1) or Endpoints?

Comment: It's most likely not an issue in your code. Eclipse setup and/or Endpoints are the likely culprits. I'm assume you're generating the library with Eclipse and not the command line?

Comment: I emailed endpoints-trusted-testers, and got a little guidance, and have been able to run it from the commandline by adding the jar to the SDK/lib/user directory, but not through Eclipse. I'm not Eclipse guru enough to figure out exactly what Eclipse is doing when it runs Endpoints...

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Objectify and Endpoints for a couple of months now. The project setup was a bit tricky, and in the end I gave up using the Eclipse Endpoint plugins, as it was proving difficult to debug. Instead I used this excellent example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven by Dan as a starting point. Using Eclipse for Java coding and command line for compiling. Using Maven & command line gives reliable and helpful feedback. Use command mvn help:describe -Dplugin=appengine for available options.

Once you have your Maven Endpoints project setup, adding Objectify to Maven is trivial. Objectify and supporting documentation is extremely straight forward and works well with Endpoints. The only hiccup I had was that Endpoints blow up if Keys and Refs aren't annotated with @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE).